# Pandas Hierarchial index from row

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, multi-index

I believe this should be a trivial problem, however I am somehow unable to find a solution.

Suppose you have the following DF

```
pd.DataFrame({'Math_0':[1,2,6,'math'],'Math_1':[8,3,7,'math'],'science_0':[9,5,2,'science']},
             index=['Jeff','Bob','Cal','Category'])
df
>>>
        M0      M1      S1
Jeff    1       8       9
Bob     2       3       5
Cal     6       7       2
Subj    math    math    science
```

I want to group by the index row 'Subj' to create a hierarchial-index 
In turn the resulting data frame would look like

```
df
>>>
      Subj      question    score
Jeff  math      m0          1
                m1          8
      science   s0          9

Bob   math      m0          2
                m1          3
      science   s0          5

Cal   math      m0          6
                m1          7
      science   s0          2
```

Answer (score 3):

IIUC after `T` do `melt`

```
yourdf=df.T.reset_index().melt(['Subj','index']).set_index(['variable','Subj']).\
          rename(columns={'index':'question','value':'score'})

yourdf
Out[19]: 
                 question score
variable Subj                  
Jeff     math          M0     1
         math          M1     8
         science       S1     9
Bob      math          M0     2
         math          M1     3
         science       S1     5
Cal      math          M0     6
         math          M1     7
         science       S1     2
```

Comment: Wow, nice answer +1

Comment: Huh, perhaps not as trivial as I had originally suspected.  That seems to be a more complex answer than what I had thought would be implemented in pandas. Thank you none the less, I will check on my DF as soon as I return to my computer